# How to click dynamic element inside span class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm pretty new in Selenium and UI automation. Have some problem with clicking on a dynamic element inside span class. So this id everytime changes for each of 3 drop-down elements. So each class for each this element the same which is create the problem as well.

So I need change the value for `id="react-select-2585057--value-item"`

```html
<div class="field loan-selection">
        <label class="field__body">
            <div class="field__label">Verwendung
                <!-- -->&nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="field__control">
                <div class="Select customSelect has-value Select--single">
                    <div class="Select-control">
                        <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2585057--value">
                            <div class="Select-value">
                                <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-2585057--value-item">Freie Verwendung</span>
                            </div>
                            <div aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2585057--value" aria-disabled="false" class="Select-input" role="combobox" style="border:0;width:1px;display:inline-block" tabindex="0"></div>
                        </span>
                        <span class="Select-arrow-zone">
                            <span class="Select-arrow"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can try this driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[@id^='react-select']"))

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example for you...

Comment: How did you try? Share your code and exception

Comment: i did try to click with default selectors and methods, but the problem is, that we jave 3 the same div each of one have dynamic elements, that need to be clicked! And everything inside that divs the same, class namesm and so on

Comment: try using xpath if the text is known : //span[contains(@clas,"Select-value-label") and contains(@id,"react") and contains(text(),"Freie Verwen")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* to invoke `click()` on the element with dynamic id as **id="react-select-2585057--value-item"** assuming this element will always be a descendent of the node `<div class="field__label">` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='field loan-selection']//div[@class='field__label' and contains(., 'Verwendung')]//following::div[1]//span[@class='Select-value-label' and starts-with(@id,'react-select-')]"))).click();
```

Comment: at this page, we have 3 element that starts with node {<div class="field loan-selection">}, shouldn't we start create xpath from this? and with tour example i have received: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Coordinates

Comment: @AkhmadSadaiev Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Great use of `starts-with()`

Comment: @DebanjabB wow, that's working!!! Now im able click this stuff. But still can't click on the list, that appeared after clicking on this label. Hold on, i will post the div. Thanks a lot at least for this one, it really helps

Comment: @AkhmadSadaiev If your requirements have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.